# Default email address on email type field

Tags: email, workflow, custom-field, email-alert, default-value

I would like to give an email field a default email address of 'test@gmail.com' onto every opportunity record in Salesforce. I need to use an an email type field for this (for setting email alerts with workflow.) Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite easy to do. Create the new custom email field on the opportunity object. During the field creation process you will be presented with a field called Default Value. For the default value enter "test@gmail.com". You have to enclose it in double quotes, because an email address is stored as a string.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had tried this and it is still not displaying on records (field still showing as blank). Any thoughts?

Comment: I've never run into this problem in any of my orgs. Are you adding this field to a standard object? Are you using a Visualforce page? Any chance you could post a screenshot of what you see when entering the default value?

Comment: The issue was that it was not working on existing opportunities. It would only work on opportunities that were newly created. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem. That makes sense, because the default value is set at the time of creation not upon editing. You could easily do a data load to manually update any existing opportunities though.